# Run node script from strapi plugin front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I'm using strapi to power up an API which delivers data to my SSR nuxtjs project.

I want to develop a strapi plugin to build my SSR nuxtjs project where the users could press a button and the project would be re-built with the new data.

I already have the code to do the above. It makes use of the “spawn_process” module and basically runs terminal commands to build and copy the project. This piece of code runs perfectly on nodejs.

The only thing I'm missing is how to call it from the plugin front-end. I have tried to put that code inside the plugin service file or in the functions folder but I always get this error:

```
error Error: Cannot find module 'spawn_process'
```

I'm pretty sure this error occurs because the code is not running on the node back end part of strapi. How can I make it run from there?

Is it possible, or perhaps there is a better approach?

Comment: Looks like you have not installed module: 'spawn_process' inside your strapi project. Check your project.json, if its listed there.